# Django Rest Framework 'Manager' object is not subscriptable

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-queryset, django-managers

I am using a custom Queryset as manager for my model like this.

```
class EmployeeQuerySet(QuerySet):
    def update(self, **kwargs):
        # some checks
        super().update(**kwargs)



class EmployeeManager(BaseManager.from_queryset(EmployeeQuerySet)):
    pass


class Employee(models.Model):
    objects = EmployeeManager
```

(In some other application related to vacations)

```
class Vacation(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
```

(Vacation application has pretty standered Serializer  and ViewSet for Vacation Model).

Error happens when I try to get `/vacation/` end point. (DRF browsable API tries to render choices for employee field.)

Everything works as expected but there is [a check in django-rest-framework (relations.py)](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L157). This check  fails for my model. Actually they are checking type against `Manager` class but my manager is of type `BaseManager` (as expected) not `Manager`.

This triggers an error by returning manager instead of queryset. Is there any way to make this check true from my side? (inheriting from `Manager` is not a choice) though I think this should be updated with a PR in DRF.

**Traceback**

```
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 904, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/defaulttags.py", line 161, in render
    values = self.sequence.resolve(context, ignore_failures=True)
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 671, in resolve
    obj = self.var.resolve(context)
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 796, in resolve
    value = self._resolve_lookup(context)
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current()
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 222, in iter_options
    self.get_choices(cutoff=self.html_cutoff),
  File "/home/nafees/.venvs/shift/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/relations.py", line 202, in get_choices
    queryset = queryset[:cutoff]
TypeError: 'EmployeeManager' object is not subscriptable
```

Comment: Show the full traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman `queryset[:cutoff]` fails because (this)[https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L155] method returns manager instead of queryset.

Comment: But that's still not enough context. Where is this manager being used? Show the whole thing, and the relevant view/serializer.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please see edit. I think my question is valid but I am not able to properly explain it (English is not primary language).

Comment: This problem at its core it that I am using `BaseManager.from_queryset(EmployeeQuerySet)` as my manager. If I inherit it from `Manager`, everything works fine. Because `BaseManager` is not an instance of `Manager` but vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Django documentation recommends the manager to inherit from `models.Manager` so does DRF.

You might be confused by the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/managers/#from-queryset) naming `BaseManager` something that's *not* `models.BaseManager` but instead a base manager that inherits from `models.Manager`.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using a `ModelManager` instead of a `Queryset`

Example :

`Employee.objects` **==>** `Employee.objects.all()`